# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't boot. Plymouth and intramfs prompt error

Tags: boot, 17.10, plymouth, initramfs, busybox

I recently installed some Plymouth themes by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-*
```

Then I changed theme to `ubuntu-budgie` using this command and selecting the theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

And then I updated configuration using this command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And finally I rebooted my system and what I see, it shows me the bootup screen, then automatically reboots the system and then takes me to some black screen prompt mentioned BusyBox and initramfs in it. What should I do now? I can't boot into my system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that any partition got corrupted somehow. Probably this can solve your problem:

1. There must be some message telling the name of the partition that got corrupted. If not, try executing `exit` command (when it shows you that screen again, may the message with corrupted partition appear).
2. Execute this:

   ```
   (initramfs) fsck <name-of-the-partition> -y
   ```
3. It'll start checking the partition and after the checking is done, reboot the system by executing `reboot`.

Done, most are the chances that system will now boot without any errors. Let me know this solves your problem or not.

Comment: Whoa. It really worked! Now I can boot into my system. Thanks.